# Modify List.get behavior in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, what's the idiomatic way to modify the behavior of `List.get` such that calling `get(-1)` returns the last element in the list?

I tried an extension:

```
operator fun <T> List<T>.get(index: Int): T {
    return this[if (index < 0) size + index else index]
}
```

But it didn't behave as desired, and I got the warning

```
scratch.kts:3:26: warning: extension is shadowed by a member: public abstract operator fun get(index: Int): T
operator fun <T> List<T>.get(index: Int): T {
                         ^
```

Comment: I think you meant `return this[if (index < 0) size + index else index]`

Comment: What's wrong with `list.last`? Clearly states what you're doing, and doesn't require index based access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't hide a member method with an extension method, the only option that will work would be to have a subclass that overrides the functionality in the way you describe.

```
class NegativelyIndexableList<T> : ArrayList<T>() {
  override fun get(index: Int): T =
    if (index < 0) super.get(size + index) else super.get(index)
}
```

However you should consider the future users of this code. It does obfuscate what's going on here.  The meaning of `list[index]` changes based on the value of `index`, and this won't be obvious in places where `list` and / or `index` are not known in advance. Consider this trivial example:

```
fun getValueFromAFewDaysAgo(timeline: List<Day>, today: Int, daysAgo: Int) =
  timeline[today - daysAgo]
```

If `today` is 2 and `daysAgo` is 7, then this method will either throw an exception (if `timeline` is a regular list) or return something from the future (if `timeline` is a `NegativelyIndexableList`).

If you really have to have this feature, then consider not conflating it with `get`. Add a new method:

```
fun getFromEnd(index: Int) = asReversed()[index]
```

Comment: beside that, you can create a proxy to provide a cyclic view. e.g: `cyclic(list)[-1]`

Comment: Instead of the overhead of `asReversed()`, you could just use `get(size - index)`

Comment: You could: that is exactly what `asReversed()` does (see ReversedViews.kt). I'd go with `asReversed()` since it is more readable, slightly reduces the chance of off-by-one errors, adds a sensible exception and is more idiomatic.

Comment: @holi-java is there an example of this? Or a link where we can read more?